# How can I set initial values for map with new Map()?

Tags: javascript, hashmap

We can do

```
let myMap = new Map()

myMap.set(keyString, "value associated with 'a string'")
myMap.set(keyObj, 'value associated with keyObj')
myMap.set(keyFunc, 'value associated with keyFunc')
```

which will work like:

```
myMap.get(keyString)    // "value associated with 'a string'"
myMap.get(keyObj)       // "value associated with keyObj"
myMap.get(keyFunc)      // "value associated with keyFunc"
```

But this process will become cumbersome if you have very large data. So is there a way like:

```
let myMap = new Map({
  keyString: value1 
  keyObj:value2
  keyFunc: value3
})
```

I know the above code is wrong, but I want to know is there a way to do that?

Comment: Pass an array of key value pairs, .. `new Map([['key', 'value'], ['key2', 'value2']])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the reference page from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) for Map, you could do it as follows:

```js
let kvArray = [['key1', 'value1'], ['key2', 'value2']]

// Use the regular Map constructor to transform a 2D key-value Array into a map
let myMap = new Map(kvArray)
```